Bathroom Ceiling Crack
Wife and I bought our first home and there are some cracks in the ceiling of our bathroom. Bathroom fan installed to avoid anymore moisture. Will a little caulk suffice or will further repair be needed?
https://postimg.cc/gallery/H8yLV8T

Starting at the left, the first and second pictures show a wrinkle in the paint.  That is an indication of moisture or water intrusion.
You need to first determine if there is still moisture or if the area has dried.
Purchase a moisture meter to test the areas. ( It is a good investment and you will be popular with neighbors who want to borrow it) Anything at 20% or higher is too high and will need to dry out. You will also need to ascertain where that moisture came from. It could just be the humidity in the bathroom and lack of using the exhaust fan.
Once the moisture level is below 20%, ( prefered below 10% ) you will need to remove the wrinkled paint and any loose paint. Then caulk the seam with the crown moulding and paint.
The third and fourth pics just show a separation that can be the result of expansion and contraction of the wood in the crown moulding. This could be from humidity as well. It can be caulked and painted, again if the moisture level is low enough.
If your bathroom does not have an exhaust fan, consider having one installed.  If you do have one, use it often. ( I turn mine on every time I use the bathroom. A Fan timer is convenient. You can set it when showering and leave the room, still the fan can run longer to pull all the moisture away. A fan should run minimum of 1 hour if a shower is used. (I install a timer with every bath fan I install.)
